# Как поменять иконку самого .apk файла (не приложения)?

Tags: android, cordova

**Дано.**

- Node.js
- Cordova
- Android Studio
- Собрал на Cordova проект для платформы Andriod.
- Собрал (Build) apk в Adnroid Studio.

На выходе есть прекрасный файл agent.apk
Всё хорошо и прекрасно, иконка приложения, после установки на телефон, отображается в наилучшем виде.

---

**Проблема.**
Но есть одно "НО":
иконка самого файла agent.apk выглядит непрезентабельно (в проводнике Windows И в проводнике Android устройста).

---

**Вопрос.**
Есть ли возможность указать иконку самого файла?

Comment: Насколько мне известно, вы не можете этого сделать. Т.к. это зависит от системы.

Comment: Если это нужно сделать на своем компьютере - [apkshellext.com](http://www.apkshellext.com/).

Comment: Благодарю за ответы @zakiroof. Так и есть. Кстати, в проводнике Android устройства эта иконка отображается нормально.

Comment: @zakiroof дал правильный ответ.
В Windows иконка файла отображается автоматически в зависимости от ассоциированой программы для открытия.

Comment: https://windowsloop.com/change-file-icon-in-windows-10/

Comment: @zakiroof, ответы - в ответы.

Answer (score 0):

Иконки файлов отображает программа, через которую вы на них смотрите (файл менеджер и т.п.)
Стоковые проводники, что на Андроиде, что в других ОС обычно знают только самые востребованные форматы, но всегда можно поставить сторонний ФМ.
А если стоковое ПО позволяет - то настроить его по вкусу.
В проводнике Windows иконку предоставляет ассоциированная программа, можно поставить расширение, которое умеет отображать иконку из самого APK.
Для Андроида - наверное любой проводник из маркета это умеет.

Соответственно со стороны разработчика приложения вы никак не можете сделать, чтобы в любом ПО ваш APK-файл отображался с вашей иконкой.